# No duplicate data

Tags: excel, vba

I want you to be able to save your answers to display them later.
With the code there are only duplicate entries and I don't know how to save the first answer and then press the button again to save the next and so on.

Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Worksheets("Quiz").Range("H7:L10").Copy Worksheets("Antworten").Range("H7")
    Worksheets("Quiz").Range("B7:F10").Copy Worksheets("Antworten").Range("B7")
    Worksheets("Quiz").Range("H14:L17").Copy Worksheets("Antworten").Range("N7")
    Worksheets("Antworten").Activate
    If IsEmpty(Range("H7")) = False Then
    Worksheets("Quiz").Range("H7:L10").Copy Worksheets("Antworten").Range("H12")
    Worksheets("Quiz").Range("B7:F10").Copy Worksheets("Antworten").Range("B12")
    Worksheets("Quiz").Range("H14:L17").Copy Worksheets("Antworten").Range("N12")
    Else
    MsgBox "Nothing saved."
    End If
End Sub
```

Picture
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1y41R.png)
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9dxp.png)

Comment: What data is duplicating? Where is the data coming from?

Comment: As you see in the second picture there are the same data. The data get copied from the first picture (its another worksheet).

Comment: you should post some examples of some inputs and corresponding correct outputs